# Show x Imageviews sequentially for y seconds

Tags: java, android, multithreading, imageview, visibility

Trying to get the following ;

ImageView x is shown for y seconds. Then, x is Invisible again and a different ImageView (z) is shown for y seconds. And so on..

I've got :

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.series_onthouden);
    hideAllImages();
    showImage(3, 2000);
    showImage(4, 1000);
}

public void showImage(int color, final int sec) {

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sec);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < myImagebtns.length; i++) {
                        ((ImageView) findViewById(myImagebtns[i]))
                                .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    if (!thread.isAlive()){
        ((ImageView) findViewById(myImagebtns[color])).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        thread.start();                     

    }
}
```

It works for the first color.. But also shows the second simultaniously. The second color should be shown when the first turns invisible (after x seconds).

ty

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `Handler` like the example below:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
im1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                im1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                im2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }
},500);
```

where `500` is the delay between events.

Repeat `postDelayed` calls for as many images as necessary.

Hope this helps!